# Reading a line from a file and removing extraneous new line chars

Tags: file, perl

I have the following code that reads from a file and loads to a hash.
This file contains only 1 line with 2 (ASCII) strings separated by a `:`

```
sub get_data {
    my $opened = open(my $fh, '<', $filename);
    if (!$opened) {
     return;
    }
    my @data = split /:/, <$fh>;                                                                                                                                                    
    my $h_data;
    $h_data->{foo} = $data[0];
    $h_data->{bar} = $data[1];
    return $h_data;
}
```

This seems to work but when I `Dumper::Dump` the return hash ref the value for the key `bar` seems to have extra whitespace/new line characters.
Should I be doing something different to remove extraneous whitespace characters?
Is there a more perl specific way for this kind of files?

Comment: *"Should I be doing something different to remove extraneous whitespace characters?"* - right now you do exactly nothing to remove these. Maybe you are not aware that `<$fh>` returns the full line, i.e. including trailing white space and newline. To remove these you might for example strip these from `$data[1]`, i.e. `$data[1] =~s/\s+\z//`

Comment: Are there more whitespaces than the newline at the end? Please show what the file looks like.

Comment: @TedLyngmo:The file's contents are: `foo:123-bar` and when I check from `vim` seems that it that after `bar` there is no extra space. But when I use `Data::Dump` I can see that it prints a new line

Comment: @Jim Ok, in that case, the first suggestion in my answer below should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there's only an unwanted newline at the end of the line:

```perl
my $line = <$fh>;
chomp $line;                  # remove a newline at the end if it's present
my @data = split /:/, $line;
```

If there are whitespaces spread out in the line:

```perl
my $line = <$fh>;
$line =~ s/\s+//g;            # remove all whitespaces from the line
my @data = split /:/, $line;
```